# Errors in displaying video by VideoView

Tags: android, android-videoview

This is the mainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.mukesh.birthdaycard;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button buttonPlayVideo2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);
//displays a video file
    VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
    String uriPath2 = "android.resource://com.example.toyo.playvideo/"+R.raw.movie;
    Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath2);
    mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
    mVideoView2.requestFocus();
    mVideoView2.start();
    buttonPlayVideo2.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            VideoView mVideoView2 = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
// VideoView mVideoView = new VideoView(this);
            String uriPath = "android.resource://com.example.toyo.playvideo/" + R.raw.movie;
            Uri uri2 = Uri.parse(uriPath);
            mVideoView2.setVideoURI(uri2);
            mVideoView2.requestFocus();
            mVideoView2.start();
        }
    });`
```

Getting errors in these:
inconvertible types:

```
(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

and

```
setOnClickListener
```

I want to just add a video on full screen and place a button on it for replay. I am just copying it from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voYDlnfcchs

Answer (score 0):

add (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1); after getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN); line and make sure the id of your button is correct and please show me your logcat

Thank you..